# Facebook api and codeigniter

Tags: php, facebook, codeigniter

I have a web app using the Facebook api and codeigniter. I currently have about 5 methods in the main controller that use the Facebook library currently all my methods look like

```
private function getFacebookLogout() {
    $config = array();
    $config['appId'] = '**************';
    $config['secret'] = '*****************';
    $config['fileUpload'] = false;
    $facebook = new Facebook($config);
    $logoutURL = $facebook -> getLogoutUrl();
    return $logoutURL;
}
```

Is there anyway to make this a little cleaner so that I don't have to write those 5 lines of code over and over again

Comment: There are literally about 10 different ways to accomplish this depending on your OOP knowledge. Put it in a `private function __construct(){ //$config and stuff }` so that it executes as soon as your class is created. Create your own library and invoke it. Create a model to handle the FaceBook stuff so that you can easily call it from other controllers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was in that situation a while back. What I did is create a simple CodeIgniter library to act as a wrapper. Here's the constructor of that library:

```
class Facebookauth
{
    function __construct()
    {
        // Get instance of CodeIgniter object
        $CI =& get_instance();

        // Include the Facebook PHP SDK
        require_once("facebook/facebook.php");

        // Create the Facebook object
        $config = array();
        $config['appId'] = $CI->config->item('facebook_app_id');
        $this->appId = $CI->config->item('facebook_app_id');
        $config['secret'] = $CI->config->item('facebook_secret');
        $this->appSecret = $CI->config->item('facebook_secret');
        $config['fileUpload'] = false;
        $this->facebook = new Facebook($config);
    }
}
```

I then just created additional methods to do various tasks, and they could access the Facebook object with `$this->facebook`. Then, I loaded it as a CodeIgniter library and was able to access it in the usual manner.

Comment: Awesome, thanks, was trying to do this through a config file and that did not work. This is a simple solution.